# add_editor_style always loads old css file from my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

`add_editor_style` always loads the old CSS file from my plugin.

My code is like below :

```
function admin_add_editor_styles() {
    $filePath = plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__);
    add_editor_style($filePath);
}
add_action( 'init', 'admin_add_editor_styles' );
```

The CSS file is dynamic. The first time it runs perfect. But when I add some css classes into the `style.css` then then newly added classes are not include into editor CSS. But if I rename the `style.css` to `style2.css` then it works.

On the admin panel there is a textarea where I can put custom CSS class and the content of the textarea is saved into `style.css` file.

Comment: the css file is dynamic. First time it runs perfect. But when I add some css classes into the style.css then then newly added classes are not include into editor css. But if I rename the style.css to style2.css then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, you should add some form of version control. Like:

```
$filePath = plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__) . '?ver=' . rand(0,100);
add_editor_style($filePath);
```

But instead of random, some internal control using `get_option` and `update_option` whenever the style is saved in your Custom CSS Editor. Something like:

```
// On the editor, when saving modifications
$old_value = get_option( 'my_css_version' );
$new_value = $old_value + 1;
update_option( 'my_css_version', $new_value );

// On style load
$version = get_option( 'my_css_version' );
$filePath = plugins_url( 'css/style.css', __FILE__) . '?ver=' . $version;
```